# Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"} when executing appium script in android emulator

Tags: java, automation, appium, appium-android

I am running the following script:
this code is to open PlayStore in android emulator

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 5 API Q");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554"); 
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "10");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.vending");
 capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
//        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");

        try {
            AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My **appium-doctor** shows all upto date but on appium server I get the error:
    [Appium logs]https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0mros5scj4mikx/Screenshot%202019-05-27%2018.25.26.png?dl=0
Added the full appium server logs.

```
 `[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.13.0
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   sessionOverride: true
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.android.vending","platformVersion":"10","automationName":"UiAutomator2","platformName":"Android","udid":"emulator-5554","deviceName":"Nexus 5 API Q"},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"appium:appActivity":"com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity","appium:appPackage":"com.android.vending","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:deviceName":"Nexus 5 API Q","platformName":"android","appium:platformVersion":"10","appium:udid":"emulator-5554"}]}}
[W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"appActivity":"com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.android.vending","platformVersion":"10","automationName":"UiAutomator2","platformName":"Android","udid":"emulator-5554","deviceName":"Nexus 5 API Q"},null,{"firstMatch":[{"appium:appActivity":"com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity","appium:appPackage":"com.android.vending","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:deviceName":"Nexus 5 API Q","platformName":"android","appium:platformVersion":"10","appium:udid":"emulator-5554"}]}]
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1559022178952 (11:12:58 GMT+0530 (IST))
[Appium] Appium v1.13.0 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.33.1) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   platformName: android
[Appium]   appActivity: com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity
[Appium]   appPackage: com.android.vending
[Appium]   automationName: UiAutomator2
[Appium]   deviceName: Nexus 5 API Q
[Appium]   platformVersion: 10
[Appium]   udid: emulator-5554
[BaseDriver] W3C capabilities {"alwaysMatch":{"platformNa... and MJSONWP desired capabilities {"appActivity":"com.google.... were provided
[BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"platformNa...
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 1cea5658-2748-4d09-964a-25687e221d84
[ADB] Using 'adb' from '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb'
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[AndroidDriver] Using device: emulator-5554
[ADB] Using 'adb' from '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb'
[ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5554
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 28
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 10
[ADB] Device API level: 28
[UiAutomator2] Relaxing hidden api policy
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings put global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps 1'
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings put global hidden_api_policy_p_apps 1'
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings put global hidden_api_policy 1'
[AndroidDriver] No app sent in, not parsing package/activity
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device'
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell echo ping'
[AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is installed
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] Using 'aapt' from '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt'
[ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal to the application version name ('2.14.0' >= '2.14.0')
[ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/io.appium.settings/apks/settings_apk-debug.apk'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f io\\.appium\\.settings'
[AndroidDriver] io.appium.settings is already running. There is no need to reset its permissions.
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell appops set io.appium.settings android\:mock_location allow'
[Logcat] Starting logcat capture
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[ADB] 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' is installed
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' is greater or equal to the application version name ('3.5.1' >= '3.5.1')
[UiAutomator2] io.appium.uiautomator2.server installation state: sameVersionInstalled
[ADB] Checking app cert for /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-v3.5.1.apk
[ADB] Using 'apksigner' from '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/apksigner'
[ADB] Starting '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/apksigner' with args '["verify","--print-certs","/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-v3.5.1.apk"]'
[ADB] apksigner stdout: Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
[ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: a40da80a59d170caa950cf15c18c454d47a39b26989d8b640ecd745ba71bf5dc
[ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 61ed377e85d386a8dfee6b864bd85b0bfaa5af81
[ADB] Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: e89b158e4bcf988ebd09eb83f5378e87
[ADB] 
[ADB] '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-v3.5.1.apk' is already signed.
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test'
[ADB] 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' is installed
[ADB] Checking app cert for /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk
[ADB] Starting '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/apksigner' with args '["verify","--print-certs","/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk"]'
[ADB] apksigner stdout: Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
[ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: a40da80a59d170caa950cf15c18c454d47a39b26989d8b640ecd745ba71bf5dc
[ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 61ed377e85d386a8dfee6b864bd85b0bfaa5af81
[ADB] Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: e89b158e4bcf988ebd09eb83f5378e87
[ADB] 
[ADB] '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' is already signed.
[UiAutomator2] Server packages are not going to be (re)installed
[UiAutomator2] Waiting up to 30000ms for services to be available
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm list instrumentation'
[UiAutomator2] Instrumentation target 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner' is available
[UiAutomator2] Forwarding UiAutomator2 Server port 6790 to 8200
[ADB] Forwarding system: 8200 to device: 6790
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward tcp\:8200 tcp\:6790'
[UiAutomator2] No app capability. Assuming it is already on the device
[ADB] Getting install status for com.android.vending
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package com.android.vending'
[ADB] 'com.android.vending' is installed
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.android.vending'
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm clear com.android.vending'
[AndroidDriver] Performed fast reset on the installed 'com.android.vending' application (stop and clear)
[UiAutomator2] Performing shallow cleanup of automation leftovers
[UiAutomator2] No obsolete sessions have been detected (Error: socket hang up)
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test'
[UiAutomator2] Starting UIAutomator2 server 3.5.1
[UiAutomator2] Using UIAutomator2 server from '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-v3.5.1.apk' and test from '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
[UiAutomator2] Waiting up to 30000ms for UiAutomator2 to be online...
[ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","instrument","-w","io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"]
[Instrumentation] io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test.AppiumUiAutomator2Server:
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[UiAutomator2] Error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized within 30000ms timeout. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output. You could also try to increase the value of 'uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout' capability. 
[UiAutomator2]     at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:78:13)
[UiAutomator2]     at UiAutomator2Server.errorAndThrow [as startSession] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/lib/uiautomator2.js:192:15)
[UiAutomator2]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[WD Proxy] Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[UiAutomator2] Did not get confirmation UiAutomator2 deleteSession worked; Error was: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Trying to proxy a session command without session id
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.android.vending'
[Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200 
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp\:8200'
[UiAutomator2] Restoring hidden api policy to the device default configuration
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps'
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps'
[ADB] Running '/Users/shivam.somani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy'
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1559022211907 (11:13:31 GMT+0530 (IST))
[W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized within 30000ms timeout. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output. You could also try to increase the value of 'uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout' capability. 
[W3C]     at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:78:13)
[W3C]     at UiAutomator2Server.errorAndThrow [as startSession] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/lib/uiautomator2.js:192:15)
[W3C]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 32957 ms - 1132
[HTTP]
```

I am using Java 11 and appium 1.13

Answer (score 0):

uninstall **uiautomator-server** and **uiautomator-server-test** app from your emulator and try to run the script again.

Run following command in command prompt to uninstall the apps:

```
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
```

And then run your automation script. That works for me when i get ECONNRESET error.

Comment: Yeah saw this answer somewhere and did that but It does not resolve the error. I get the same error

Comment: Can you add full appium server log?

Comment: edited in the question, added full logs of appium server

Comment: add **uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout** capability in Your DesiredCapability and set its value to 50000

Comment: same issue still, tried with 50000 and 100000 value.`        capabilities.setCapability("uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout", "50000");
`